# How to get the layout ID of an activity programmatically at runtime

Tags: android, layout, resources

I have a reference to an activity, but I don't know the ID of content view for the activity. 
I need to find all the views in the layout.
Can I get the ID of the layout of an activity programmatically at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can get layout id  but you ca try with

```
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()
```

and from here you can get any child view you want

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I don't understand your question, but I think you may get views by there ID using:

View v = activity.findViewByID(*required ID*)